# encoding html table for csv download

Tags: javascript, html, angular, download

I have implemented the following function to download the html table as csv:

```
  exportTable(table_id: string) {
    let separator = ",";
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table#" + table_id + " tr");
    var csv = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
            var data = (cols[j] as HTMLElement).innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").replace(/(\s\s)/gm, " ");
            row.push(data);
        }
        csv.push(row.join(separator));
    }
    var csv_string = csv.join("\n");
    // Download it
    var filename = "export_" + table_id + ".csv";
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.style.display = "none";
    link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    link.setAttribute("href", "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));
    link.setAttribute("download", filename);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

The problem I have is that the csv file then contains chars that could not be decoded for example:

```
â€ƒ
â€¯
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It's easy to find a robust JavaScript library for generating CSV using Google. Don't reinvent the wheel. You'll make a square one.

Comment: Create blob instead of base64 URL. Then create url with `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`